# xCode Build Error in trying to build command line for Briefs wireframes

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

i am trying to compile the "compact-briefs"-target of Brief (http://github.com/capttaco/Briefs) with xCode.

But every time i run build i get this error:

> target specifies product type
>   'com.apple.product-type.tool', but
>   there's no such product type for the
>   'iphonesimulator' platform

**Whats wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

a tool (command line utility) is not a valid target for iOS.

specifically, your choices when targeting iOS are:

- application
- static library

you'll need to create a new target in Xcode (probably a static library) to compile this program (and remove the `main` entry if building a static library). technically, you could alter the existing target -- but i recommended creating a new one because changing the existing target could break something for somebody else.